# Check browser width in component, store in variable then use in template in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to say whether a sidenav should be opened or not based on the deviceWidth property which comes from the component. For some reason it is not working.

**Here is the html:**

```
<md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="deviceWidth > 960">
```

**Here is what my component looks like:**

```
export class AppComponent {
  deviceWidth: any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.deviceWidth = window.innerWidth;
  }
}
```

Comment: `[opened]="deviceWidth > 960"`

Comment: @adam-beck I also noticed that opened="{{ deviceWidth > 960 }} works does this make sense?

Comment: If it works it works, I guess. But I don't like interpolation in my arguments. I would recommend using the `[ ]` binding syntax.

Comment: use what @adam-beck suggested, it would be correct use of property binding..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrong way (not exactly wrong but not proper),

```
[opened]="{{deviceWidth>960}}"
```

Correct way,

```
[opened]="(deviceWidth>960)"
```

And maybe `resize` function of `window` would also be needed (later) as shown,

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event: any) {
    console.log(event.target.innerWidth);
    this.deviceWidth = event.target.innerWidth;
  }
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. Can you explain how the HostListender can help. Are you telling me to put this in my component?

Comment: Also, I do not have access to the opened directive, that is built in to the Angular Material component if you were telling me to add HostListener to the directive. But if it can be added to Component can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

if `opened` is declared as `@Input` in your `md-sidenav` component then your syntax is wrong. It has to be

```
<md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" [opened]="deviceWidth > 960">
```

check these links for more details

https://toddmotto.com/passing-data-angular-2-components-input
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html